# jQuery - building a banner with a timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to build a banner that says "Loading", and hides when the application is done.

```
<div id="ajaxBanner"></div>


function ajaxBanner(action, confirmMsg) {

    if (action == 'show') {
        $('#msg').text('Loading...');
        $('#ajaxBanner').show();
    } else if (action == 'hide') {
        $('#ajaxBanner').fadeOut();
    } else if (confirmMsg == true) {
        $('#ajaxBanner').show();
        ajaxBanner_timeout = setTimeout(ajaxBanner('hide'), 2000);
    }
};
```

The function shows a "Loading" banner message to the user and later hides it. The thing is, I also want to use this space for confirmation messages, like "XXXX Added to XXX".

The problem is, when confirmMsg is true, it is getting killed by a subsequent AJAX call with does Action show.

How can I say only do action==show or action==hide when the ajaxBanner_timeout is complete?

Comment: If ajaxBanner_timeout == 0 then it is complete.

Comment: what about on first load, by default on loads it's just var ajaxBanner_timout.. isn't that nil?

Comment: I tried a  if (ajaxBanner_timeout == 0) {... but that didn't work. Where do I need to define  ajaxBanner_timeout?

Comment: ajaxBanner_timeout is simply a reference to the setTimeout event you created.  In cases where you wanted to prevent the timeout from firing, you could use clearTimeout(ajaxBanner_timeout).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is setTimeout() does not take a function call it takes a string or an anonymous function try `setTimeout("ajaxBanner('hide')", 2000);`.  Right now the function is immediately called no pause.  Another method is

```
setTimeout(function(){
  //do something;
},2000);
```

Note this is the better way.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are calling ajaxBanner('hide') in your setTimeout instead of passing in the function reference.  Wrapping your ajaxBanner('hide') in an anonymous function will solve the problem:

```
 setTimeout(function() { ajaxBanner('hide'); }, 2000);
```

**Explanation/Test you can do in your JavaScript Console:**

One way to see the difference is to paste this in your [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) console and run it:

**Good:**

```
 // alert fires in 5 seconds
 setTimeout(function() { alert('hide'); }, 5000);
```

**Bad:**

```
 // alert fires right away, despite the 5 second delay
 setTimeout(alert('hide'), 5000);
```

**UPDATE:** Note that I am not assigning the setTimeout event to a variable as it's not needed in the above code example in the question.

Comment: Thanks that's cool but the problem is that then blocks future calls. given that .. function ajaxBanner(action, confirmMsg) {

 if (ajaxBanner_timeout == 0) {
.... the banner will never clear. And I think I need that if because I want to block future ajaxBanner calls from replacing the current banner. Thoughts?

Comment: I could always set the timeout to do the actual fadeout instead calling a function...

Comment: @AnApprentice - ajaxBanner_timeout isn't the counter, it's just a reference to the timeout event.  That will never work.  You don't need it.  Also, check my answer again.  Just call setTimeout without assigning it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ajaxBanner_callback = function (){};
function ajaxBanner(action, confirmMsg) {

  if (action == 'show') {
      var ajaxBanner_callback = function () {
        $('#msg').text('Loading...');
        $('#ajaxBanner').show();
      }
     if (!ajaxBanner_timeout) ajaxBanner_callback();
  }
  else if (action == 'hide') {
      var ajaxBanner_callback = function () {
        $('#ajaxBanner').fadeOut();
      }
     if (!ajaxBanner_timeout) ajaxBanner_callback();
  }
  else if (confirmMsg == true) {
      $('#ajaxBanner').show();
      ajaxBanner_timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        ajaxBanner_callback();
        clearTimeout(ajaxBanner_timeout);
        ajaxBanner_callback = function (){};
      }, 2000);
  }
};
```

You can do the same to the `confirmMsg` if you want.

It might be useful investigating into [$.queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/)

Comment: If you simply want your code to stop executing while the timeout is running, then use one of the other answers, but this prevents all code from running while the timeout is running, and then calls it afterwards. This means you can queue multiple actions and much cooler stuff.